# PHP Sql-Server Populate HTML table rows in a loop, and input submit issue

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I have a page which performs a lookup on a database and outputs the following

SUP-1, YES

In my database other than the SUP code the other value is either a YES or NO

I have created a page which outputs the row, and then has the function of updating the database via POST method only values that can change are YES to NO and NO to YES

See my form

```
<?php
            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
                echo "<form action=thispage.php method=post>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['sup_code'] . " </td>";
                $result = $row['has_loan'] == "YES" ? "YES" : "NO";
                $result2 = $result == "YES" ? "YES" : "NO";
                echo "<td>" . "<select name=loan>
                  <option selected>" . $row['has_loan'] . " </option>
                  <option value=$result2>$result2</option>
                </select></td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</form>";             
            }

        ?>
```

Im trying to out put into the select input value the current status YES or NO but then also trying to update the database if value is changed.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: no you are not doing it right at all

Comment: for every row you are creating a <form> conceptually. which may be fine for a windows MDI app with a Windows pull down menu. But for a browser, much snarling and gnashing of teeth

Comment: @DrewPierce Would you have a suggestion on how I can do this properly? I have multiple rows so it's important to have a form for each.

Comment: fair enough. i could hack something together but will let the html guys take a better stab at it

Comment: @DrewPierce - I don't see issues with 1000 forms on a page, but you will see some with 1 form and 1001 inputs. ( hashdos yea! )  http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/PHP-5-3-9-released-with-hash-DoS-fix-1407472.html

Comment: @DrewPierce no problem fella, you think a radio button solution would be better?

Comment: i just don't know why the screen would be littered with hundreds of submit buttons but who am i

Comment: @DrewPierce depends on application..

Comment: why not just create an html doc manually, display it in your browser, and show us a typical screen. you could post the html of the manual effort, or screen shot it and plop a picture in a link or in your question